# Как использовать регулярки в качестве своебразной маски? Python

Tags: python

Не смог разобраться. Условно я имею строку: `id 32 value("Lorem, ipsum")`, где 32 и Lorem, ipsum - могут быть любой длины. Как мне без использования сторонних библиотек, получить что-то такое: `{"id":32, "value": "Lorem, ipsum"}` Как я могу с учетом того, что содержание перечисленных элементов будет произвольной длинны и с произвольными символами (кроме " ", которые ограничивают значение внутри) сделать что-то вроде универсальной маски для этого?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def parse(string):
    output = {}

    data = string.split()

    output['id'] = data[1]
    output['value'] = ' '.join(data[2:]).replace('value', '')[2:][:-2]

    return output

print(parse('id 32 value("Lorem, ipsum")'))
```